# 'AppKit.framework/AppKit.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, appkit

Xcode outputs an error when I try to import `<AppKit.framework/AppKit.h>`, even though the file exists.

Example script:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit.framework/AppKit.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that line to:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

And also make sure that `AppKit.framework` is added to the list of included frameworks in your project.

Comment: How do you add the AppKit.framework to the list of included frameworks easily? Can you automate the process when writing `#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>`?

Comment: You can drag & drop the framework into the list of Frameworks in your project or you can go to the "Files" menu and choose the "Add Files to _______" function, where you can then select the AppKit framework (usually found in /System/Library/Frameworks or /Developer/SDKs/______/System/Library/Frameworks/ -- insert your SDK MacOS version there)